# For what values $​​a, b$ ​​parabola $y = ax^2$ will be tangent with the line $y=2x+b$?

Tags: derivatives

> For what values $​​a, b$ ​​parabola $y = ax^2$ will be tangent with the line $y=2x+b$?

Do I need the derivative of the equations? Or one of them then compare between them?

1. $y=ax^2$
2. $y=2x+b$

Comment: If they are tangent, that means that their intersection is only one point

Comment: It might be helpful to the OP to post more details about this statement to provide more guidance as an answer. Regards

Comment: It is a little dangerous to characterize tangent lines as "intersecting the curve in one point" in general, since the tangent line may intersect in more than one point.  (E.g. the line tangent to $\sin(x)$ at $x=\pi/2$. (Granted, though, that it is harmless in the case of a parabola :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tangent to the parabola will be of the form:
$$y^1 = 2ax$$
This is equal to $2x+b$ only when:
$$2ax = 2x+b$$
Comparing co-efficients gives you:
$$(a,b)=(1,0)$$

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

1-Two functions intersects, so we have to solve $ax^2=2x+b$.

2- The derivation of $y=ax^2$ (which is $2ax$) is $2$ when $x$ is one of above quadratic equation's solutions.

Comment: Very nice hints...follow those, and you're "there"! +1

Comment: @BabakS.: I think different problems call for different answers and sometimes clear hints are spot on! Regards

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: If they are tangent, that means that their intersection is only one point. That means that:
$$
ax^2 = 2x+b
$$
has only one solution!